# Model validation attribute [Required] doesn't accept a string of all spaces

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model, attributes, string

I'm working with ASP.Net MVC 4 website project.

When I set the attribute `Required` for a model property.

```
[Display(Name = "Some Model Property:")]
[Required]
public string SomeModelProperty{ get; set; }
```

This will mark the input field to be red when its value is empty.

My issue is that this field is also marked red when its value is **all spaces**

I want to allow input value to have all spaces only for a `Required` property.

How can I get to that?

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
```

And if the length of the string matters add:

```
[MinLength(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own `ValidationAttribute` to do the job.

```
public class MostlyRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString());
    }
}

[Display(Name = "Venue Assigned Abstract Tracking Number:")]
[MostlyRequired]
public string SomeModelProperty{ get; set; }
```

Comment: And where should I put these code to get it work for all of my model?

Comment: It's not overly important where you put attribute classes and it depends on your solution architecture. The important thing is to group similar classes together somewhere.

Comment: I don't get the idea how this code get connected to the generated javascript validation script on client side. May you help me?